# Struggling with Parallax Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm working on my personal site, and everything(for the most part) goes on the index page. The first 3 sections worked fine, but the last section seems to be broken. I think it could be because of the flex, but I'm not sure.

Thank you guys for the help:)

Also, I know my images are probably messed up in the pen, I know. I'm gonna go back and put in media queries to fix them

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/developbir/pen/YaYyEX)

**HTML**

```
  <h2>Explore my Work</h2>
  <div class='imageContainer'>
    <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>



  </div>

</div>

<div class="contact">
  <h3>Hello World</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myWork {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

  background:linear-gradient(#333,#5a5454);
  height:100%;
  width:100%;



}
.myWork h2 {
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 4%;
  font-size: 4em;
  color:white;
  text-shadow: -4px 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.myWork img {
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;

  border:4px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
.myWork img:hover{
  box-shadow:   0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
                0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
                0 16px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
                0 32px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15),
                0 64px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-out;
}
.imageContainer {
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  justify-content: space-around;

}
.contact {
  height:75%;
  background-color:green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;

}
```

Comment: give the body the gradient not the div

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need .myWork to be positioned absolute, if you don't need, by removing position: absolute I think it will fix your issue.

Your problem appears from height: 100% of .myWork combined with position: absolute.

Comment: I was actually fiddling around earlier and this worked. I always try and work with something before asking for help, but it's super easy to get frustrated! Thank you!